# Performance issue with dynamically building table with ng-repeat in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, performance, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was trying to dynamically generate a table from an array of objects.

Code look like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in ::rowCollection">
  <td ng-repeat="column in ::columns">
    {{::row[column.field]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried using one time binding, but the initialization is just very very slow.

I just need to display the table, no need to have any two way bindings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, There is an other solution which I opted for my applications in such a scenario.

Prepare HTML on server side and just display it in Browser with [html binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

because in such a situation when you have multiple outer/inner loops its better to use high performance Server CPU instead of low CPUs on client side.

This link is kind of relevant as it helps understanding why Server Side rending is better.[Link](http://www.onebigfluke.com/2015/01/experimentally-verified-why-client-side.html)